# Как подключить модули к проекту в Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Есть исходники одного проекта. Хочу собрать билд для тестов. При компиляции возникает ошибка.
No such module "SwiftLocation"[image: Ошибка компиляции]

На самом деле операция
import SwiftLocation
еще при вводе сообщает, что такого модуля не видит.

Установил cocoapods, добавил в файл podfile указанные модули.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘9.0’
target 'FindMeEasily' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for FindMeEasily
pod ‘Alamofire’, ‘3.5.0’
pod 'PKHUD', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftLocation', '~> 1.0.5'
end
```

В терминале запустил pod install
[image: Pod install]
Но все равно эти модули в проекте не видны.
В настройках сборки проекта убирал флажок ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
Не помогло..
Как включить этот модуль и два других в проект?

Comment: После установки воркспейс открываете?

Comment: Да, открываю в workspace

Comment: Ваш pod файл покажите

Comment: Какая версия Xcode?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fjt0hm
Версия Xcode 8.3.2 (8E2002)

Comment: # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘9.0’

target 'FindMeEasily' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FindMeEasily

pod ‘Alamofire’, ‘3.5.0’
pod 'PKHUD', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftLocation', '~> 1.0.5'
end

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fjt2bu в папке Pods почему PodFile файл не виден. Он есть в каталоге проекта, когда смотришь в терминале командой ls

Answer (score 1):

Версия Xcode у Вас 8.3.2, т.е. Swift 3, а Вы подключаете библиотеки, глядя на содержимое подфайла, для Swift 2.

Посмотрите внимательно документацию  библиотекам на GitHub: [SwiftLocation](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftLocation) - версия 2.0.7. Либо прописывайте ее в подфайле, либо вообще без указания версии:

```
pod 'SwiftLocation'
```

Так же пройдитесь по другим библиотекам.

---

Для проверки создайте новый пустой проект. Закройте Xcode. В терминале перейдите в папку проекта. Создайте pod:

```
pod init
```

откройте

```
open podfile
```

и пропишите в подфайле для проверки одну библиотеку

```
pod 'SwiftLocation'
```

закройте, поставьте:

```
pod install
```

Откройте воркспейс и проверьте.

Comment: удалил информацию о версии, но это не помогло.
На самом деле проект компилировался успешно в прошлом году осенью, когда была среда Swift 2. А сейчас обновился Xcode и вылезли эти ошибки...
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘9.0’

target 'FindMeEasily' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FindMeEasily

pod ‘Alamofire’
pod 'PKHUD'
pod 'SwiftLocation'
end

Comment: @RustaDolokhov после удаления сделали pod update?

Comment: Сделал update после вашего ответа. И почти поверил в удачу! Обновленные версии модулей на самом деле скачались и были заменены! Смотрите скрин http://prntscr.com/flrlp5 .. но после Product->Clean, Product-Build опять та же ошибка...Помогите, пожалуйста, мне кажется мы почти у цели.. 99%! Может удаленно подключитесь? telegram "veresk"

Comment: @RustaDolokhov воркспейс в Xcode переоткрывали?

Comment: Да, открыл. Обновление вышло Xcode небольшое - обновил. Сделал снова update и install

Comment: помогите пожалуйста. Я готов денег заплатить )

Comment: @RustaDolokhov не горячитесь, посморите обновление в ответе.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fpsa7y  http://prntscr.com/fpsaeo http://prntscr.com/fpsalo не работает... не подключен модуль пишет

Comment: нет идей больше?